# Idioma en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de imprimir en mi pagina la fecha con el siguiente formato Miércoles, 05 de Febrero de 2020, para lo cual en la base de datos lo almaceno asi: 2020-02-05 pero al momento de hacer el echo sale asi: Friday, 15 de November de 2019. en este caso ya modifique el confg.php de mi pagina.

> $config['language']   = 'spanish';

descargue la carpeta de con la información del idioma y la guarde donde corresponde. Y agregue en el auto load.

> $autoload['language'] = array('calendar','date');>

```
   $fecha_ingeso = $dato['fecha_prox_aud_date'];
   $fecha2 = new DateTime($fecha_ingeso);
   $customFormat='l\, d \d\e F \d\e Y';
   $fecha2= $fecha2->format($customFormat);
```

con ese  codigo le doy el formato al la fecha y luego hago el echo:

```
 <td scope="row"><?php echo $fecha2;?></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso lo puedes hacer de una forma mucho más sencilla.

Pasa la fecha a la vista tal cual como la tienes en la `Base de Datos` y en tu vista al inicio del archivo pones lo siguiente:

```
<?php setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES", 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish'); ?>
```

Después para imprimir tu fecha en ese formato puedes hacerlo con:

```
<?php echo strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime($tufecha)) ?>
```

No es necesario que realices modificaciones dentro del `config.php`. Si quieres ver más parametros de `strftime()` puedes verlo en la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php).